# Loading asset using rootBundle in Flutter web application - unexected null value error

Tags: flutter, config, assets

I've problem with `rootBundle.loadString($path)`function call. I want to load config from yaml file asset and create `Config` custom object on it's base in my **web application**. But I get error `Unexpected null value`. I can't handle it, have someone had simmilar problem?

**Flutter doctor**:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.3.0-17.0.pre.225, on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS 5.4.0-74-generic, locale pl_PL.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.3.0-17.0.pre.225 at /opt/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2794dea0df (3 days ago), 2021-06-05 16:04:04 -0400
    • Engine revision 03d645e782
    • Dart version 2.14.0 (build 2.14.0-182.0.dev)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /usr/lib/android-sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /usr/lib/android-sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /usr/lib/android-sdk
    • Java binary at: /usr/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~18.04-b10)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more details.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
    • cmake version 3.19.2
    • ninja version 1.8.2
    • pkg-config version 0.29.1

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.23.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Redmi Note 8 Pro (mobile) • 4lfmlflvfms8lbd6 • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
    • Linux (desktop)           • linux            • linux-x64      • Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS 5.4.0-74-generic
    • Chrome (web)              • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212
```

**Error**:

```
Error: Unexpected null value.
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:5056:11)
    at Object.nullCheck (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:5381:30)
    at load (http://localhost:40177/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:2240:33)
    at load.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:37463:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:37494:7)
    at asset_bundle.PlatformAssetBundle.new.load (http://localhost:40177/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:2238:20)
    at asset_bundle.PlatformAssetBundle.new.loadString (http://localhost:40177/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:2110:32)
    at loadString.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:37463:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:37494:7)
    at asset_bundle.PlatformAssetBundle.new.loadString (http://localhost:40177/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:2109:20)
    at http://localhost:40177/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:2191:83
    at IdentityMap.new.putIfAbsent (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:25663:21)
    at asset_bundle.PlatformAssetBundle.new.loadString (http://localhost:40177/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:2191:57)
    at create (http://localhost:40177/packages/egm/config/config.dart.lib.js:25:60)
    at create.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:37463:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:37494:7)
    at Function.create (http://localhost:40177/packages/egm/config/config.dart.lib.js:24:20)
    at main$ (http://localhost:40177/packages/egm/main.dart.lib.js:230:42)
    at main$.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:37463:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:37494:7)
    at main$ (http://localhost:40177/packages/egm/main.dart.lib.js:228:18)
    at main (http://localhost:40177/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:33:29)
    at main.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:37444:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:37315:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:32550:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:33077:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:33115:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:32963:23)
    at http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:32214:46
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:37315:59)
    at _FutureListener.then.handleValue (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:32550:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:33077:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:33115:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:32963:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:32984:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:37567:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:37573:13)
    at http://localhost:40177/dart_sdk.js:33323:9
```

**Config class code**:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:yaml/yaml.dart';

class Config {
  /// private constructor
  Config._(dynamic yamlConfig)
      : communication =
            CommunicationConfig.fromYaml(yamlConfig["communication"]);

  /// Factory method
  static Future<Config> create(final String path) async {
    dynamic yamlRawConfig = await rootBundle.loadString(path); //! ERROR
    dynamic yamlConfig = loadYaml(yamlRawConfig);
    return Config._(yamlConfig);
  }

  CommunicationConfig communication;
}

class CommunicationConfig {
  CommunicationConfig.fromYaml(dynamic communication)
      : address = communication["address"];
  String address = "";
}
```

**Creating config in main**:

```dart
void main() async {
  dynamic app = MyApp();
  Config config = await Config.create("assets/config.yaml");
  Communication(messagesHandler: MessagesHandler(), config: config);
  runApp(app);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` at the begining of your `main` function.

```dart
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Your code here...
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you're trying to do to work, you will need to ensure that the pubspec.yaml has the necessary flutter assets declared correctly

Comment: If this is the solution then do not ask questions. If this is just a comment the please remove it as this space is reserved only for solutions